# C# Impersonation technique

Tags: c#

I wanted to remove a config file from a remote machine having IP as : sj1slm612. Now the problem is i do not have full modification rights to that remote machine, so I'm using impersonation technique to do this. Normally when I'm connected to this remote machine via putty, I use 'sudo'. So my question is will the following code be able to solve my problem ? Thanks.

My Code :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            using (WindowsIdentity Authorized_user = new WindowsIdentity("sj1slm612\\wtsnqa", "password"))
            {
                using (WindowsImpersonationContext context = Authorized_user.Impersonate())
                {
                    File.Delete(@"/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/standalone-full.xml");
                    File.Delete(@"/apps/instances/query_13100/configuration/standalone-full.xml");
                    File.Delete(@"/apps/instances/wppapi_13200/configuration/standalone-full.xml");
                    File.Delete(@"/apps/instances/wppgui_13300/configuration/standalone-full.xml");

                    Console.WriteLine("All config files removed from sj1slm612");
                    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: No, currently the remote machine on which i wanted to try is currently down, but i would be needing it to do some necessary operations on this remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your approach:

1. You are trying to impersonate a remote machine account on a local machine; this won't work.  The credentials of a machine account can only be validated by that machine.  In addition, that account has no rights on the local machine, so it doesn't really make sense to impersonate it.  You need to impersonate a domain account.  When you use a tool like putty, the credentials are sent to the remote machine and not validated by the local machine.  This is why you can use a machine account of the remote machine.
2. You need to give proper paths for the files.  Nowhere do you indicate that these files are on the remote machine.  Use something like `"\\machine\c$\path\to\file"`.

The details on what are going to work or not will depend on your network and OS, which you didn't specify, though it sounds Linux-ish.  There may be a different syntax for referring to remote files that you need to use.

Comment: Did you mean...  Use something like "\\machine\c$\path\to\file"?  With two backslashes before the machine?

Comment: Yes, and that's actually what I typed.  SO broke it.

Comment: I figured it was a typo or something like that. :)

Comment: @bmm6o : I understood your answer, for point no. 2, i corrected my path and my code is able to hit that path, but however i am not able to impersonate remote user, i am not sure what exact thing to do in my code. however this thing works via putty : sudo -S -u wtsnqa rm /path of file/....

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit but the problem isn't with your code, it's with your approach.  You can't use a machine account to do this, use a domain account or make use of services on the remote machine (like putty does).

Comment: Do you understand the fundamental difference between what your code is attempting to do and how running `rm` in putty works?  The authentication mechanisms are totally unrelated, and one can make use of credentials that are not usable by the other.